# How can I tell which Enterprise Mode a site is using in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11

We have implemented the Enterprise Mode Site List and have a few sites in there working as expected at various emulation mode levels.

For one particular internal site, we used IE's Developer Tools (F12) to determine which emulation mode makes the site work.  We walked back through all of the modes under Browser Profile = Desktop, but none worked.  Then we switched to Browser Profile = Enterprise, and started trying those.  The answer was:

```
Browser Profile = Enterprise
Document mode = Edge
```

Now we need to configure this site in the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager tool, but it is unclear which setting to choose.  That's one part of the question.

Once we configure it, we'd like to go to a user's machine, open the site, and then somehow verify that it is indeed using the expected emulation mode.

If I hit F12 for Development Tools, it's really not clear whether it is telling me the emulation level currently being used on the page that is open, or if it's just showing whatever setting was there last.

What is the correct way to determine which emulation mode is actually being used by a page?  If I knew that, I wouldn't have to ask the first question because I could check for myself.  :)

Oh, and I was hoping to avoid turning on the logging feature that Enterprise Mode has.  It would probably tell me what I need to know, but I'm trying to keep it simple and not add any overhead.